# Encode certificate (.crt) into X509

Tags: swift, x509, asn.1

So we have certificate file (.crt) in android we encode it with the following code:

```
    CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = getAppContext().getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.newCertificate);
        X509Certificate publicCert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(is);
        return publicCert.getEncoded();
    } finally {
        //....omitted
    }
```

the above codes returns `byte[]` of ***X.509 encoded as ASN.1 DER***. Now we need to do this in swift. Anyone have any idea to do this in swift or point me where to start?

Comment: This is old question, we already changed how we handle certificate files both on android and iOS. On iOS we use [SwiftyRSA](https://github.com/TakeScoop/SwiftyRSA) to get the public and private key from PEM file.